# Cassandra Table Design

Tags: database-design, cassandra, nosql

Can anybody explain the following in a more verbose manner?  In particular, it would help me greatly to see a description without the terms "higher order duplication" and "keywords" (which do not appear to be explained).

> Table design must take into account the possibility of higher order
>   duplication, such as unlimited keywords stored in a large number of
>   rows. A case of n keywords stored in m rows is not a good table
>   design. You should rethink the table schema for better design, still
>   keeping the query foremost.

This is an extract from here: https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.3/cql/ddl/dataModelingAnalysis.html

I understand the concept of having the same data in multiple tables to reduce the need to join data from multiple tables programatically.  Are the 2 quoted sentences highlighting some scenarios where the level of duplication becomes problematic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the documentation is basically trying to drive in the idea of what de-normalization can do. They use the cyclist name as example. That could appear in multiple rows as it's denormalized (unlike a relational structure). Due to redundancy/duplication/denormalization your storage consumption can grow much faster than with a relational database.

The other thing I believe they're referring to is that if you have something like, say, categories (essentially a column value of type "list"), where all rows have many categories (possibly an infinite number of categories), you could end up with a lot of data due to duplication - which could have an impact on your query response and space consumption. You should think carefully about the design to determine how often, say, the categories are required for the queries. If it isn't that often, maybe a better table design could come into play (e.g. splitting the list off into a separate table that a subsequent query would satisfy on the small sets of queries that would require it). In short, the idea is to momentarily pause before implementation to ensure your design makes sense in a distributed/replicated environment.

That's what I gathered from the documentation.

-Jim